# How to add transition while lazy loading images with fullpage.js

Tags: scroll, lazy-loading, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js on my page. I set scrollbar:true,so i want to track scroll position on certain slide to make images load on reveal. If there's a way to use lazy load for images with transition effect on scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fullPage.js provides lazy loading, [check it out](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#lazy-loading).

```
<img data-src="image.png">
<video>
    <source data-src="video.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source data-src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```